# Confused about where to store keys for Android App Signings

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I have a few questions related to signing my android app, getting ready for release.

1) Does the path to your keystore have to be located in your project files? Or just anywhere on my computer, like my Desktop?

2) If I do need to keep in located in my project files, how do I make sure I hide the key when I push a commit to my public GitHub repo? Is all I have to do add *.jpk to the gitignore file or are there more files I need to hide from the GitHub repo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to store it in the project files. Just keep it in a secure location on your computer, and it's always a good idea to keep a backup somewhere else yet. You will need the key when you sign your app again in the future (such as when you make a new release).

Comment: Doesn't the password get stored in build.gradle, which is usually included in repos? I saw online that the way you should protect that is to create a file called keystore.properties and hide your passwords there. Now wouldn't that have to go in the project files? And should that then be added to gitignore?

Comment: My password never gets stored in the build.gradle. When I make a signed apk for the first time, I make a keystore and store it on my pc. Then I make the passwords and store those somewhere too. There are a couple more fields to fill in and then you make your signed apk. When you want to update your app, make another signed apk and use the keystore and passwords you made before. For more info, check these sites: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing and https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/generate-signed-apk-android-studio.html  hope this helps :-)

Comment: You could create the keystore.gradle as you said. And make sure you ignore it. The in your app build.gradle load it and use the data present there. Anyway store it and back it up in a secure location. The keystore.gradle is so you won't need to type it every time you want to sign your app